# How to trigger a method when session ends in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Know that when a session is running on a web page after login, the session ends when user logs out or when the browser is closed, i want to know how to trigger a method when the session ends on browser close.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As @gleng has pointed out, this question has already been asked. In fact, a web search of "c# session end" would have taken you to that same post here. There is a great wealth of knowledge and experience here for you to peruse. And as I've discovered for myself, I'm seldom the first person to encounter a particular issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call it in `Session_End` method in global.asax.

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) 
{
    // Call your method  
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) i frogot about global.asax :p